# How to use '<' in html without warning

Tags: html

No problem to run the code or display the html
but I just want no warning with my code;

I need to type '<' on html text because of my client wanted this;

This is example code
< 4 < part makes trouble;

/input> < 4 <

Invalid character was used in the text string (< 4 <)

And I'm Sorry that I'm using Japanese eclipse so I translate warning message on my own.
maybe some words or form? is wrong with original error message.

Thank you

Comment: You can use html entities `&lt;` = "<" so `</h3> &lt; 4 &lt; ...`

Comment: oh, thank you for super fast answer :D

Comment: I don't understand why this got a downvote. The question is clear and answerable. Not everyoneknows the full HTML specification from there head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for '<' and '>' respectively. Here is link which will help for html escape characters
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes

Comment: one more useful site added to my favorite, thank you!